# EJB java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: jsf, jpa, eclipselink, ejb-3.0

I have a java.lang.IllegalStateException in EJB.

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class SalesRequestSession {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "IPMSPU")
    private EntityManager em;
    @Resource
    private javax.transaction.UserTransaction utx;

    public void persist(Object object) {
        try {
            utx.begin();
            em.persist(object);
            utx.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "exception caught", e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public Customer insertNewCustomer(Customer cust){
        try{
            persist(cust);
            Query query = em.createNamedQuery("Customer.findByName");
            query.setParameter("name", cust.getName());
            return (Customer)query.getSingleResult();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    public Request insertNewRequest(Request request) {
        persist(request);
        return getInsertedRequest();
    }

    public Request getInsertedRequest() {
        return (Request) em.createNamedQuery("Request.getInserted").getSingleResult();
    }

    public List<Request> getRequestByEmployee(Employee emp){
        Query query = em.createNamedQuery("Request.findBySalesId");
        query.setParameter("salesid", emp);
        return query.getResultList();
    }

    public List<Customer> getAllCustomers(){
        return em.createNamedQuery("Customer.findAll").getResultList();
    }
}
```

that occures when i try to insert new Customer by calling method insertNewCustomer from a managedbean

and here is the exception details

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Operation not allowed.   at
>   com.sun.enterprise.transaction.UserTransactionImpl.checkUserTransactionMethodAccess(UserTransactionImpl.java:146)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.transaction.UserTransactionImpl.begin(UserTransactionImpl.java:162)
>     at
>   boudy.sessionbeans.SalesRequestSession.persist(SalesRequestSession.java:35)
>     at
>   boudy.sessionbeans.SalesRequestSession.insertNewCustomer(SalesRequestSession.java:46)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1052)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1124)
>     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:5388)
>     at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:619)
>     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
>     at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:571)    at
>   org.jboss.weld.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:42)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:861)
>     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
>     at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:571)    at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doAround(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:162)
>     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:144)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:861)
>     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
>     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:370)
>     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.**intercept(BaseContainer.java:5360)
>     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:5348)
>     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:214)
>     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:89)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy222.insertNewCustomer(Unknown Source)    at
>   boudy.sessionbeans.__EJB31_Generated_*SalesRequestSession*_Intf_***Bean*_.insertNewCustomer(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   boudy.beans.SalesRequestBean.submitAddCustomerAction(SalesRequestBean.java:135)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   javax.el.BeanELResolver.invokeMethod(BeanELResolver.java:779)     at
>   javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:528)   at
>   javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:257)     at
>   com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:248)  at
>   com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:302)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:39)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
>     at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)    at
>   javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
>     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)    at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
>     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
>     at boudy.filters.LoginFilter.doFilter(LoginFilter.java:114)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
>     at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
>
> SEVERE: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   Operation not allowed.    at
>   boudy.sessionbeans.SalesRequestSession.persist(SalesRequestSession.java:40)
>     at
>   boudy.sessionbeans.SalesRequestSession.insertNewCustomer(SalesRequestSession.java:46)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1052)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1124)
>     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:5388)
>     at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:619)
>     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
>     at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:571)    at
>   org.jboss.weld.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:42)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:861)
>     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
>     at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:571)    at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doAround(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:162)
>     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:144)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:861)
>     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
>     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:370)
>     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.**intercept(BaseContainer.java:5360)
>     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:5348)
>     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:214)
>     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:89)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy222.insertNewCustomer(Unknown Source)    at
>   boudy.sessionbeans.__EJB31_Generated_*SalesRequestSession*_Intf_***Bean*_.insertNewCustomer(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   boudy.beans.SalesRequestBean.submitAddCustomerAction(SalesRequestBean.java:135)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   javax.el.BeanELResolver.invokeMethod(BeanELResolver.java:779)     at
>   javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:528)   at
>   javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:257)     at
>   com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:248)  at
>   com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:302)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:39)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
>     at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)    at
>   javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
>     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)    at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
>     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
>     at boudy.filters.LoginFilter.doFilter(LoginFilter.java:114)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
>     at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Operation not allowed.   at
>   com.sun.enterprise.transaction.UserTransactionImpl.checkUserTransactionMethodAccess(UserTransactionImpl.java:146)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.transaction.UserTransactionImpl.begin(UserTransactionImpl.java:162)
>     at
>   boudy.sessionbeans.SalesRequestSession.persist(SalesRequestSession.java:35)
>     ... 85 more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default session beans use container-managed transaction demarcation. When container manages transaction there is no need to use *UserTransaction*.

Calling methods of *UserTransaction* is not allowed from the methods of session bean when container-managed transaction demarcation is in use. Calling those will lead to IllegalStateException. This restriction is documented for example in EJB 3.1 specification, chapter 4.7.2.